# What is the difference between "this" and "that"

Tags: differences, pronouns, this-that

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using “that” and “this” interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably)
>   [Is there a clear delineation between the usages of 'this' and 'that' in American English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/is-there-a-clear-delineation-between-the-usages-of-this-and-that-in-american)

Is there a specific rule about when to use the word "this" or the word "that"? I have heard people say "this clock", and I have also heard people use it in the context "this city". Overall, I'm very confused.

Comment: The difference between "this" and "that" is a basic element of English grammar. If you have a more specific question we may be able to help you, but until then I'm voting to close this as General Reference.

Comment: Related: [Using 'that' and 'this' interchangeably](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably), [Is there a clear delineation between the usages of 'this' and 'that' in American-English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/is-there-a-clear-delineation-between-the-usages-of-this-and-that-in-american) and ['… things like this.' vs. '… things like that.'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75042/things-like-this-vs-things-like-that)

Comment: Have a look at the aforementioned questions. As it stands, your question is a bit too basic for this site, but you might wish to support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: https://askanydifference.com/difference-between-this-and-that/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this quote here by Michael Swan (Practical English Usage), and he says (page 589): "We use this/these for people and things which are close to the speaker. We use that/those for people and things which are more distant from speaker, or not present."

Furthermore, in the book "English Grammar Today" (Cambridge) we can read: "We sometimes use *this*, *these*, *that*, *those* to identify emotional distance. We use *this* and *these* to refer to things that we feel positive about, that we are happy to be associated with, or we approve of. We use *that* and *those* to create distance."

Comment: I agree with _this_.

Comment: I like the _emotional distance_ part. I had an intuitive grasp for that concept, but could not put it in words the way that book does.

Answer (score -2):

It is very similar to the French constructions of **voici** and **voila**, which generally mean "*this  here*" and "*that there*" respectively.

Comment: No, they don’t.

Comment: Better said 'Here it is" and "There it is".

Comment: If I had to "translate" them, I'd just say they're *"See **this**"* and *"See **that**"*.