# This, that and it for non-material objects

Tags: word-choice, this-that, it-this

The question is not about how to use "this, that, it" with material objects, but how to use them with **non-material** ones? I don't understand (it, that, this) yet.

For example:

> I go to a gym every day and I like (it, this, that?).
>
> You helped me and (it, this, that) is very good.

Is there any rule about (again it, this, that?)?

Suggestions? Can I use "this, that, it" interchangeably in **most** situations?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4325 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/73830 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/75042 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/35781

Comment: @tchrist, there is nothing about "it" there.

Comment: Exactly the way you'd do with 'material' (tangible?) objects.

Answer (score 5):

> I go to a gym every day and I like it.

I would understand "it" to refer to the object of the sentence - you like the gym.

> I go to a gym every day and I like that.

I would understand "that" to refer to the whole phrase - you like *going to* the gym. Alternatively, it may mean that you like the fact that you go *every day*.

> I go to a gym every day and I like this.

Awkward, as per [Using "that" and "this" interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably)

> You helped me and it is very good.

Confusing: "it" here doesn't seem to be referring to any thing.

> You helped me and this is very good.

Again, awkward.

> You helped me and that is very good.

Meaning, the fact that you helped me is very good.

Comment: why are you using "would", "may"? Is this implying that, in fact, in can be said differently ("that", "it", "this") and you are not sure?

Comment: No, I'm implying that I'm speculating about how I would tend to interpret these sentences generally - but they are somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Alright. Is there a precise, definite rule about using "this, that, it" with non-material objects?

Comment: No. Read the answers from tchrist's links, e.g. http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4330/1236

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention "non-material" objects? Where did that come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the three interchangeably in certain cases but not all. In your examples, I would use the following:

> I go to the gym every day and I like *it*.
>
> I go to the gym every day and I really like *that*. This makes the sentence a little ambiguous as if there's something you want to point at, which is not the case in this example.
>
> You helped me and it's kind of you. You helped me and that's kind of you.

I wouldn't  really use *this* in this instance because that would make it less idiomatic.

Comment: so there is no rule about that except only a feeling of when to them?

Comment: @Alex: There's but it wouldn't work in every case.

Comment: @Alex As Kris has already said in a comment below your question, the 'rule' is the same whether the object is 'material' or 'non-material'.