# "Is this code relevant for me?" vs "Is that code relevant for me?"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Someone email me message with code and I would like to ask him if the code that he sent is relevant for me.

I thought to send email back with this sentence:

> Is this code relevant for me?

Also, I am not sure what is the differences between **this** and **that**, so the sentence below sound's good to me:

> Is that code relevant for me?

Thank you.

Comment: This and that, like here and there,  are used to 'place' things in space (either physical or mental) with regard to either the speaker or the listener. We use 'this' to talk about something close to us (usually within arms reach) and 'that' to talk about something further away. We do the same thing with these words when we are talking about mental distance. You can use either 'this code'  or 'that code'  depending on how close  you wish to say the code is to you–in your mind's eye. See https://www.thoughtco.com/deictic-expression-deixis-1690428

Comment: The context completely defines this. If you and me are talking about the code we have on the screen in front of us, I would call it "this code". If you and me are talking about the code that a colleague has written, I would say "that code". However, if we're talking about that colleague's code (in comparison to something that a company abroad has written), then I would call it "this code" (because it's closer to us than that international code snippet). It's impossible to answer this in a way that would always make sense, as it is different for every context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a clear delineation between the usages of 'this' and 'that' in American English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/is-there-a-clear-delineation-between-the-usages-of-this-and-that-in-american)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use "this" for one object (singular) which is here (near to us).

Example: This is a book in my hand.

Use "that" for one object (singular) which is there.

Example: That is his car over there.