# Nearly or Almost

Tags: grammar

The words *nearly* and *almost* seem to be interchangeable to me. I can't think of any instance when one can be used where the other cannot.

eg:

- I almost fell
- I nearly fell

Are there any circumstances where this is not possible and if so, what is the reason?

Comment: There could be several situations where one would be preferable over the other, and some where one is appropriate and one isn't. See usage examples. Devoid of context, the words are quite interchangeable, yes.

Comment: related: [How do you tell if synonyms of “almost” default to meaning “less than”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73457/how-do-you-tell-if-synonyms-of-almost-default-to-meaning-less-than)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *I **almost** hesitate to [tell you]* [- about 44,600 results in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20is%20the%20remnants%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20almost%20hesitate%20to%22&tbm=bks)
>    *I **nearly** hesitate to say* [- 5 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20almost%20hesitate%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20nearly%20hesitate%20to%22&tbm=bks)

...that there certainly *are* contexts where only one word is valid/likely to be used....

> *OP very **nearly** missed [the point]* [- about 16,100 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22so%20nearly%20missed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22very%20nearly%20missed%22&tbm=bks)
>    *He very **almost** missed it* [- **no** written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22so%20almost%20missed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22very%20almost%20missed%22&tbm=bks)

---

As to the *reason* for such marked differences in "acceptability", I think with the first pair it's because idiomatically we often use ***almost*** to indicate that the words following aren't *quite* to be taken literally. The second pair seems to suggest ***nearly*** can be qualified by other modifiers, whereas ***almost*** can't.

Comment: Excellent examples. I could only manage 'The Nearly Man'.

Comment: You felt almost triumphant there :)

Comment: @mplungjan: In which context I think one could make out a case for there being a *semantic* distinction between *"I was nearly triumphant"* and *"I was **almost** triumphant"*. The former being more likely to be understood as meaning *I **came close to** winning*, but didn't quite make it*, whereas the latter might be understood as *I felt an emotion similar to 'triumphalism', but that's **not exactly the right word***. I might well have actually "won" in the second version, but that's unlikely in the first version.

Answer (score 0):

More examples:

1. I almost never travel by bus.  There are almost no apples on the tree this year (you can't use nearly in these sentences).
2. My mobile rang so often, I nearly threw it in the river (I was tempted to, but I didn't).   You could use almost here, but it sounds rather odd.  Nearly is better.

I'm not sure where this website is based.  I am in South-East England and speak "standard" British English.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Caroline. It doesn't really matter where the website is "based"; it's members are world-wide and speak many different versions of English. Sometimes it matters, often not. Enjoy the differences you will encounter :-)